# How to send auto email on wp on event trigerred

Tags: wordpress

I am newbie in PHP/Wordpress development, i want to modify the eshop, now eshop plugin does'not send auto email when we marked order as shipped, for this we have to write manually email after clicking on email id.

I want to make auto send email when order changed to shipped. For this i try to find a plugin but there is no such plugin until now, or atleast i dont find it

Below i have mentioned the code of form which actually post the detail to PHP_Self, but the thing is id does not the id, i want to make a seperate function in the page which does'not effect any other functionality, but when user send the information the function send the email.

**Here it checks the id of the checkbox, checked field**

```
                <td headers="transid numb'.$c.'">'.$myrow->transid.'</td>'.

                '<td headers="bulk numb'.$c.'"><label for="move'.$c.'">Move #'.$c.'</label><input type="checkbox" value="'.$checkid.'" name="move[]" id="move'.$c.'" />'

                ."</td></tr>\n";
```

**Here it checks Select the action and send it**

```
            <fieldset id="changestat"><legend><?php _e('Change Orders Status','eshop'); ?></legend>

            <p class="submit eshop"><label for="mark"><?php _e('Mark orders as:','eshop'); ?></label>

            <select name="mark" id="mark">

            <option value="Sent"><?php _e('Shipped','eshop'); ?></option>

            <option value="Completed"><?php _e('Active','eshop'); ?></option>

            <option value="Pending"><?php _e('Pending','eshop'); ?></option>

            <option value="Waiting"><?php _e('Awaiting Payment','eshop'); ?></option>

            <option value="Failed"><?php _e('Failed','eshop'); ?></option>

            <option value="Deleted"><?php _e('Deleted','eshop'); ?></option>

            </select>

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?php echo $_GET['action']; ?>" />

            <input type="hidden" name="change" value="yes" />

            <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="<?php _e('Change','eshop'); ?>" /></p>

            </fieldset></form>
```

**Here it actually process**

```
if(isset($_POST['mark']) && !isset($_POST['change'])){

$mark=$_POST['mark'];

$checkid=$_POST['checkid'];

$query2=$wpdb->get_results("UPDATE $dtable set status='$mark' where checkid='$checkid'");

do_action( 'eshop_order_status_updated', $checkid, $mark );

echo '<div class="updated fade">'.__('Order status changed successfully.','eshop').'</div>';

}



if(isset($_POST['change'])){

if(isset($_POST['move']) && $_POST['move'][0]!=''){

    foreach($_POST['move'] as $v=>$ch){

        $mark=$_POST['mark'];

        $query2=$wpdb->get_results("UPDATE $dtable set status='$mark' where checkid='$ch'");

        do_action( 'eshop_order_status_updated', $ch, $mark );

    }
```

Kindly guide me how can i send the auto email when it marked as shipped, which is

```
 <option value="Sent"><?php _e('Shipped','eshop'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As visible from your code, shop executes an action every time an order status is updated. THis will allow you to hook into the action without modifying the core plugin files (create your own plugin with the code or put it in your theme's functions.php) which means that the plugin will be upgrade-safe. you can read more about how wordpress actions work [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)

```
add_action('eshop_order_status_updated', 'send_user_email', 2);

function send_user_email($id, $mark) {
    if ($mark == 'Sent') {

         // your email code here

    }
}
```

First we add an action, we specify that we want our function to receive 2 parameters from the action. Then there is the function itself, we check that the new status is 'Sent' (because this action runs on every status change) and then we can insert any custom code.